# Flutter / Dart - JSON list to display in widget - shows only one value

Tags: json, flutter, dart

New to flutter and dart trying to program my first app.
I am pulling JSON data from an API which works.

The JSON response is the following:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "description": "OK",
        "message": "OK",
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "2432",
                        "name": "Tile, Modified 1 x 2 with Bar Handle",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 38
                    },
                    "color_id": 3,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "3005",
                        "name": "Brick 1 x 1",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 5
                    },
                    "color_id": 5,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "3022",
                        "name": "Plate 2 x 2",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 26
                    },
                    "color_id": 85,
                    "quantity": 3,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "3024",
                        "name": "Plate 1 x 1",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 26
                    },
                    "color_id": 3,
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "extra_quantity": 1,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "3069bpx7",
                        "name": "Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with White 100 Paper Bill Money Pattern",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 39
                    },
                    "color_id": 6,
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "4733",
                        "name": "Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Studs on 4 Sides",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 7
                    },
                    "color_id": 85,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "4740",
                        "name": "Dish 2 x 2 Inverted (Radar)",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 116
                    },
                    "color_id": 3,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "4871",
                        "name": "Slope, Inverted 45 4 x 2 Double with 2 x 2 Cutout",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 32
                    },
                    "color_id": 3,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "30663",
                        "name": "Vehicle, Steering Wheel Small, 2 Studs Diameter",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 72
                    },
                    "color_id": 86,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "43898",
                        "name": "Dish 3 x 3 Inverted (Radar)",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 116
                    },
                    "color_id": 11,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "4697b",
                        "name": "Pneumatic T Piece Second Version &#40;T Bar with Ball in Center&#41;",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 159
                    },
                    "color_id": 86,
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "extra_quantity": 1,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "44674",
                        "name": "Vehicle, Mudguard 2 x 4 with Headlights Overhang",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 77
                    },
                    "color_id": 3,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "98721",
                        "name": "Minifigure, Weapon Batman Batarang &#40;2 Bat Wings with Bar in Middle&#41;",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 19
                    },
                    "color_id": 11,
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "extra_quantity": 1,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "61780",
                        "name": "Container, Box 2 x 2 x 2 - Top Opening",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 10
                    },
                    "color_id": 85,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "64644",
                        "name": "Minifigure, Utensil Telescope",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 18
                    },
                    "color_id": 120,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "64728",
                        "name": "Minifigure, Utensil Dynamite Sticks Bundle",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 18
                    },
                    "color_id": 5,
                    "quantity": 5,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "85861",
                        "name": "Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Open Stud",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 28
                    },
                    "color_id": 5,
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "extra_quantity": 1,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "92280",
                        "name": "Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip on Top",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 27
                    },
                    "color_id": 3,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "98138pb007",
                        "name": "Tile, Round 1 x 1 with Black Eye with Pupil Pattern",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 812
                    },
                    "color_id": 1,
                    "quantity": 3,
                    "extra_quantity": 1,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "98100",
                        "name": "Cone 2 x 2 Truncated",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 21
                    },
                    "color_id": 69,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "11476",
                        "name": "Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip on Side &#40;Horizontal Grip&#41;",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 27
                    },
                    "color_id": 3,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "85984pb127",
                        "name": "Slope 30 1 x 2 x 2/3 with Red, White, and Silver Buttons, Dark Red Screens Pattern",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 33
                    },
                    "color_id": 85,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "35464",
                        "name": "Slope 45 1 x 1 Double",
                        "type": "PART",
                        "category_id": 31
                    },
                    "color_id": 4,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "extra_quantity": 1,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "sh647",
                        "name": "The Penguin - Bright Waistcoat",
                        "type": "MINIFIG",
                        "category_id": 768
                    },
                    "color_id": 0,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "sh650",
                        "name": "Harley Quinn - Jacket Open, Corset",
                        "type": "MINIFIG",
                        "category_id": 768
                    },
                    "color_id": 0,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "sh689",
                        "name": "Batman - Light Bluish Gray Suit with Yellow Belt, Black Crest, Mask and Cape &#40;Type 3 Cowl&#41;",
                        "type": "MINIFIG",
                        "category_id": 768
                    },
                    "color_id": 0,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "match_no": 0,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "item": {
                        "no": "40453-1",
                        "name": "Batman vs. The Penguin & Harley Quinn blister pack",
                        "type": "INSTRUCTION",
                        "category_id": 768
                    },
                    "color_id": 0,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "extra_quantity": 0,
                    "is_alternate": false,
                    "is_counterpart": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I then used quicktype.io to get myself the dart code - Bricklink.dart:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final bricklink = bricklinkFromJson(jsonString);

import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Bricklink bricklinkFromJson(String str) => Bricklink.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String bricklinkToJson(Bricklink data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Bricklink {
    Bricklink({
        required this.meta,
        required this.data,
    });

    Meta meta;
    List<Datum> data;

    factory Bricklink.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Bricklink(
        meta: Meta.fromJson(json["meta"]),
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

  get length => null;

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "meta": meta.toJson(),
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    Datum({
        required this.matchNo,
        required this.entries,
    });

    int matchNo;
    List<Entry> entries;

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        matchNo: json["match_no"],
        entries: List<Entry>.from(json["entries"].map((x) => Entry.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "match_no": matchNo,
        "entries": List<dynamic>.from(entries.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Entry {
    Entry({
        required this.item,
        required this.colorId,
        required this.quantity,
        required this.extraQuantity,
        required this.isAlternate,
        required this.isCounterpart,
    });

    Item item;
    int colorId;
    int quantity;
    int extraQuantity;
    bool isAlternate;
    bool isCounterpart;

    factory Entry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Entry(
        item: Item.fromJson(json["item"]),
        colorId: json["color_id"],
        quantity: json["quantity"],
        extraQuantity: json["extra_quantity"],
        isAlternate: json["is_alternate"],
        isCounterpart: json["is_counterpart"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "item": item.toJson(),
        "color_id": colorId,
        "quantity": quantity,
        "extra_quantity": extraQuantity,
        "is_alternate": isAlternate,
        "is_counterpart": isCounterpart,
    };
}

class Item {
    Item({
        required this.no,
        required this.name,
        //required this.type,
        required this.categoryId,
    });

    String no;
    String name;
    //Type type;
    int categoryId;

    factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        no: json["no"],
        name: json["name"],
        //type: typeValues.map[json["type"]],
        categoryId: json["category_id"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "no": no,
        "name": name,
        //"type": typeValues.reverse[type],
        "category_id": categoryId,
    };
}

enum Type { PART, MINIFIG, INSTRUCTION }

final typeValues = EnumValues({
    "INSTRUCTION": Type.INSTRUCTION,
    "MINIFIG": Type.MINIFIG,
    "PART": Type.PART
});

class Meta {
    Meta({
        required this.description,
        required this.message,
        required this.code,
    });

    String description;
    String message;
    int code;

    factory Meta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Meta(
        description: json["description"],
        message: json["message"],
        code: json["code"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "description": description,
        "message": message,
        "code": code,
    };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
    Map<String, T> map;
    late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

    EnumValues(this.map);

    Map<T, String> get reverse {
        if (reverseMap == null) {
            reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
        }
        return reverseMap;
    }
}
```

Following some other guides I was able to create a flutter app which shows a list.
The list is aligned to the number of items in the JSON output (in above example 27 lines), whereas it only shows the requested item in all 27 lines, instead of the full list.

My further code:

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'JsonParseDemo.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main () {
  runApp(HomeApp());
}

class HomeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: JsonParseDemo(),
      );
  }
}
```

services.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'Bricklink.dart';

class Services {
  //
  static const String url = 'https://api.bricklink.com/api/store/v1/items/set/40453-1/subsets?instruction=true&break_minifigs=false&break_subsets=true';

  static Future<Bricklink> getUsers() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
        'Authorization':
            'HIDDEN',
        'Cookie':
            'HIDDEN'
      });
      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
       Bricklink users =  jsonDecode(response.body);
        return users;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed To Load Data');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed To Load Data');
    }
  }
}
```

And the last piece including the widget - JsonParseDemo.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'Services.dart';
import 'Users.dart';
import 'Bricklink.dart';

class _JsonParseDemoState extends State<JsonParseDemo> {

  Bricklink? _bricklink;
  var _loading = false;
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;
    Services.getUsers().then((bricklink) {
      setState(() {
        _bricklink = bricklink;
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_loading ? 'Loading...' : 'BrickLink'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: null == _bricklink ? 0 : _bricklink!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Bricklink bricklink = _bricklink!;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(bricklink.data[3].entries[0].item.no),
              subtitle: Text(bricklink.data[3].entries[0].item.name),
              leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text(bricklink.data[3].entries[0].quantity.toString())),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class JsonParseDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  //
  JsonParseDemo() : super();
 
  @override
  _JsonParseDemoState createState() => _JsonParseDemoState();
}
```

I understand that my use of

```
title: Text(bricklink.data[3].entries[0].item.no),
subtitle: Text(bricklink.data[3].entries[0].item.name),
```

results in pulling only the 4th entry in the JSON response, but how would I pull the full list into the widget?

Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: set item count as bricklink.data.length instead of bricklink.length because you are iterating over the data. Next, notice the itemBuilder has an index in it so use that to build your widget. Example: title: Text(bricklink.data[index].entries[0].item.no),

Comment: awesome! Thanks Afridi, that was the missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

add your index in the data array

```
bricklink.data[index].entries[0]
```

**ListWidget**

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: null == _bricklink ? 0 : _bricklink!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Bricklink bricklink = _bricklink!;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(bricklink.data[index].entries[0].item.no),
              subtitle: Text(bricklink.data[index].entries[0].item.name),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                  child:
                      Text(bricklink.data[index].entries[0].quantity.toString())),
            );
          },
    )
```

**SampleCode**

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final bricklink = bricklinkFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

Bricklink bricklinkFromJson(String str) => Bricklink.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String bricklinkToJson(Bricklink data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Bricklink {
  Bricklink({
    required this.meta,
    required this.data,
  });

  Meta meta;
  List<Datum> data;

  factory Bricklink.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Bricklink(
        meta: Meta.fromJson(json["meta"]),
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
      );

  get length => null;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "meta": meta.toJson(),
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    required this.matchNo,
    required this.entries,
  });

  int matchNo;
  List<Entry> entries;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        matchNo: json["match_no"],
        entries:
            List<Entry>.from(json["entries"].map((x) => Entry.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "match_no": matchNo,
        "entries": List<dynamic>.from(entries.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Entry {
  Entry({
    required this.item,
    required this.colorId,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.extraQuantity,
    required this.isAlternate,
    required this.isCounterpart,
  });

  Item item;
  int colorId;
  int quantity;
  int extraQuantity;
  bool isAlternate;
  bool isCounterpart;

  factory Entry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Entry(
        item: Item.fromJson(json["item"]),
        colorId: json["color_id"],
        quantity: json["quantity"],
        extraQuantity: json["extra_quantity"],
        isAlternate: json["is_alternate"],
        isCounterpart: json["is_counterpart"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "item": item.toJson(),
        "color_id": colorId,
        "quantity": quantity,
        "extra_quantity": extraQuantity,
        "is_alternate": isAlternate,
        "is_counterpart": isCounterpart,
      };
}

class Item {
  Item({
    required this.no,
    required this.name,
    //required this.type,
    required this.categoryId,
  });

  String no;
  String name;

  //Type type;
  int categoryId;

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        no: json["no"],
        name: json["name"],
        //type: typeValues.map[json["type"]],
        categoryId: json["category_id"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "no": no,
        "name": name,
        //"type": typeValues.reverse[type],
        "category_id": categoryId,
      };
}

enum Type { PART, MINIFIG, INSTRUCTION }

final typeValues = EnumValues({
  "INSTRUCTION": Type.INSTRUCTION,
  "MINIFIG": Type.MINIFIG,
  "PART": Type.PART
});

class Meta {
  Meta({
    required this.description,
    required this.message,
    required this.code,
  });

  String description;
  String message;
  int code;

  factory Meta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Meta(
        description: json["description"],
        message: json["message"],
        code: json["code"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "description": description,
        "message": message,
        "code": code,
      };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(HomeApp());
}

class HomeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: JsonParseDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class Services {
  //
  static const String url =
      'https://api.bricklink.com/api/store/v1/items/set/40453-1/subsets?instruction=true&break_minifigs=false&break_subsets=true';

  static Future<Bricklink> getUsers() async {
    try {
      final response = await get(Uri.parse(url),
          headers: {'Authorization': 'HIDDEN', 'Cookie': 'HIDDEN'});
      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
        Bricklink users = jsonDecode(
            '{ "meta": { "description": "OK", "message": "OK", "code": 200 }, "data": [ { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "2432", "name": "Tile, Modified 1 x 2 with Bar Handle", "type": "PART", "category_id": 38 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3005", "name": "Brick 1 x 1", "type": "PART", "category_id": 5 }, "color_id": 5, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3022", "name": "Plate 2 x 2", "type": "PART", "category_id": 26 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 3, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3024", "name": "Plate 1 x 1", "type": "PART", "category_id": 26 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3069bpx7", "name": "Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with White 100 Paper Bill Money Pattern", "type": "PART", "category_id": 39 }, "color_id": 6, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4733", "name": "Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Studs on 4 Sides", "type": "PART", "category_id": 7 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4740", "name": "Dish 2 x 2 Inverted (Radar)", "type": "PART", "category_id": 116 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4871", "name": "Slope, Inverted 45 4 x 2 Double with 2 x 2 Cutout", "type": "PART", "category_id": 32 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "30663", "name": "Vehicle, Steering Wheel Small, 2 Studs Diameter", "type": "PART", "category_id": 72 }, "color_id": 86, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "43898", "name": "Dish 3 x 3 Inverted (Radar)", "type": "PART", "category_id": 116 }, "color_id": 11, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4697b", "name": "Pneumatic T Piece Second Version &#40;T Bar with Ball in Center&#41;", "type": "PART", "category_id": 159 }, "color_id": 86, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "44674", "name": "Vehicle, Mudguard 2 x 4 with Headlights Overhang", "type": "PART", "category_id": 77 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "98721", "name": "Minifigure, Weapon Batman Batarang &#40;2 Bat Wings with Bar in Middle&#41;", "type": "PART", "category_id": 19 }, "color_id": 11, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "61780", "name": "Container, Box 2 x 2 x 2 - Top Opening", "type": "PART", "category_id": 10 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "64644", "name": "Minifigure, Utensil Telescope", "type": "PART", "category_id": 18 }, "color_id": 120, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "64728", "name": "Minifigure, Utensil Dynamite Sticks Bundle", "type": "PART", "category_id": 18 }, "color_id": 5, "quantity": 5, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "85861", "name": "Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Open Stud", "type": "PART", "category_id": 28 }, "color_id": 5, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "92280", "name": "Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip on Top", "type": "PART", "category_id": 27 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "98138pb007", "name": "Tile, Round 1 x 1 with Black Eye with Pupil Pattern", "type": "PART", "category_id": 812 }, "color_id": 1, "quantity": 3, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "98100", "name": "Cone 2 x 2 Truncated", "type": "PART", "category_id": 21 }, "color_id": 69, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "11476", "name": "Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip on Side &#40;Horizontal Grip&#41;", "type": "PART", "category_id": 27 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "85984pb127", "name": "Slope 30 1 x 2 x 2/3 with Red, White, and Silver Buttons, Dark Red Screens Pattern", "type": "PART", "category_id": 33 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "35464", "name": "Slope 45 1 x 1 Double", "type": "PART", "category_id": 31 }, "color_id": 4, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "sh647", "name": "The Penguin - Bright Waistcoat", "type": "MINIFIG", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "sh650", "name": "Harley Quinn - Jacket Open, Corset", "type": "MINIFIG", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "sh689", "name": "Batman - Light Bluish Gray Suit with Yellow Belt, Black Crest, Mask and Cape &#40;Type 3 Cowl&#41;", "type": "MINIFIG", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "40453-1", "name": "Batman vs. The Penguin & Harley Quinn blister pack", "type": "INSTRUCTION", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] } ] }');
        return users;
      } else {
        Bricklink users = jsonDecode(
            '{ "meta": { "description": "OK", "message": "OK", "code": 200 }, "data": [ { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "2432", "name": "Tile, Modified 1 x 2 with Bar Handle", "type": "PART", "category_id": 38 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3005", "name": "Brick 1 x 1", "type": "PART", "category_id": 5 }, "color_id": 5, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3022", "name": "Plate 2 x 2", "type": "PART", "category_id": 26 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 3, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3024", "name": "Plate 1 x 1", "type": "PART", "category_id": 26 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3069bpx7", "name": "Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with White 100 Paper Bill Money Pattern", "type": "PART", "category_id": 39 }, "color_id": 6, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4733", "name": "Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Studs on 4 Sides", "type": "PART", "category_id": 7 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4740", "name": "Dish 2 x 2 Inverted (Radar)", "type": "PART", "category_id": 116 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4871", "name": "Slope, Inverted 45 4 x 2 Double with 2 x 2 Cutout", "type": "PART", "category_id": 32 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "30663", "name": "Vehicle, Steering Wheel Small, 2 Studs Diameter", "type": "PART", "category_id": 72 }, "color_id": 86, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "43898", "name": "Dish 3 x 3 Inverted (Radar)", "type": "PART", "category_id": 116 }, "color_id": 11, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4697b", "name": "Pneumatic T Piece Second Version &#40;T Bar with Ball in Center&#41;", "type": "PART", "category_id": 159 }, "color_id": 86, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "44674", "name": "Vehicle, Mudguard 2 x 4 with Headlights Overhang", "type": "PART", "category_id": 77 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "98721", "name": "Minifigure, Weapon Batman Batarang &#40;2 Bat Wings with Bar in Middle&#41;", "type": "PART", "category_id": 19 }, "color_id": 11, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "61780", "name": "Container, Box 2 x 2 x 2 - Top Opening", "type": "PART", "category_id": 10 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "64644", "name": "Minifigure, Utensil Telescope", "type": "PART", "category_id": 18 }, "color_id": 120, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "64728", "name": "Minifigure, Utensil Dynamite Sticks Bundle", "type": "PART", "category_id": 18 }, "color_id": 5, "quantity": 5, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "85861", "name": "Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Open Stud", "type": "PART", "category_id": 28 }, "color_id": 5, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "92280", "name": "Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip on Top", "type": "PART", "category_id": 27 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "98138pb007", "name": "Tile, Round 1 x 1 with Black Eye with Pupil Pattern", "type": "PART", "category_id": 812 }, "color_id": 1, "quantity": 3, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "98100", "name": "Cone 2 x 2 Truncated", "type": "PART", "category_id": 21 }, "color_id": 69, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "11476", "name": "Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip on Side &#40;Horizontal Grip&#41;", "type": "PART", "category_id": 27 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "85984pb127", "name": "Slope 30 1 x 2 x 2/3 with Red, White, and Silver Buttons, Dark Red Screens Pattern", "type": "PART", "category_id": 33 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "35464", "name": "Slope 45 1 x 1 Double", "type": "PART", "category_id": 31 }, "color_id": 4, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "sh647", "name": "The Penguin - Bright Waistcoat", "type": "MINIFIG", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "sh650", "name": "Harley Quinn - Jacket Open, Corset", "type": "MINIFIG", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "sh689", "name": "Batman - Light Bluish Gray Suit with Yellow Belt, Black Crest, Mask and Cape &#40;Type 3 Cowl&#41;", "type": "MINIFIG", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "40453-1", "name": "Batman vs. The Penguin & Harley Quinn blister pack", "type": "INSTRUCTION", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] } ] }');
        return users;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Bricklink users = Bricklink.fromJson(jsonDecode(
          '{ "meta": { "description": "OK", "message": "OK", "code": 200 }, "data": [ { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "2432", "name": "Tile, Modified 1 x 2 with Bar Handle", "type": "PART", "category_id": 38 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3005", "name": "Brick 1 x 1", "type": "PART", "category_id": 5 }, "color_id": 5, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3022", "name": "Plate 2 x 2", "type": "PART", "category_id": 26 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 3, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3024", "name": "Plate 1 x 1", "type": "PART", "category_id": 26 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "3069bpx7", "name": "Tile 1 x 2 with Groove with White 100 Paper Bill Money Pattern", "type": "PART", "category_id": 39 }, "color_id": 6, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4733", "name": "Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Studs on 4 Sides", "type": "PART", "category_id": 7 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4740", "name": "Dish 2 x 2 Inverted (Radar)", "type": "PART", "category_id": 116 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4871", "name": "Slope, Inverted 45 4 x 2 Double with 2 x 2 Cutout", "type": "PART", "category_id": 32 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "30663", "name": "Vehicle, Steering Wheel Small, 2 Studs Diameter", "type": "PART", "category_id": 72 }, "color_id": 86, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "43898", "name": "Dish 3 x 3 Inverted (Radar)", "type": "PART", "category_id": 116 }, "color_id": 11, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "4697b", "name": "Pneumatic T Piece Second Version &#40;T Bar with Ball in Center&#41;", "type": "PART", "category_id": 159 }, "color_id": 86, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "44674", "name": "Vehicle, Mudguard 2 x 4 with Headlights Overhang", "type": "PART", "category_id": 77 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "98721", "name": "Minifigure, Weapon Batman Batarang &#40;2 Bat Wings with Bar in Middle&#41;", "type": "PART", "category_id": 19 }, "color_id": 11, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "61780", "name": "Container, Box 2 x 2 x 2 - Top Opening", "type": "PART", "category_id": 10 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "64644", "name": "Minifigure, Utensil Telescope", "type": "PART", "category_id": 18 }, "color_id": 120, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "64728", "name": "Minifigure, Utensil Dynamite Sticks Bundle", "type": "PART", "category_id": 18 }, "color_id": 5, "quantity": 5, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "85861", "name": "Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Open Stud", "type": "PART", "category_id": 28 }, "color_id": 5, "quantity": 4, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "92280", "name": "Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip on Top", "type": "PART", "category_id": 27 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "98138pb007", "name": "Tile, Round 1 x 1 with Black Eye with Pupil Pattern", "type": "PART", "category_id": 812 }, "color_id": 1, "quantity": 3, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "98100", "name": "Cone 2 x 2 Truncated", "type": "PART", "category_id": 21 }, "color_id": 69, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "11476", "name": "Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Clip on Side &#40;Horizontal Grip&#41;", "type": "PART", "category_id": 27 }, "color_id": 3, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "85984pb127", "name": "Slope 30 1 x 2 x 2/3 with Red, White, and Silver Buttons, Dark Red Screens Pattern", "type": "PART", "category_id": 33 }, "color_id": 85, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "35464", "name": "Slope 45 1 x 1 Double", "type": "PART", "category_id": 31 }, "color_id": 4, "quantity": 2, "extra_quantity": 1, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "sh647", "name": "The Penguin - Bright Waistcoat", "type": "MINIFIG", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "sh650", "name": "Harley Quinn - Jacket Open, Corset", "type": "MINIFIG", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "sh689", "name": "Batman - Light Bluish Gray Suit with Yellow Belt, Black Crest, Mask and Cape &#40;Type 3 Cowl&#41;", "type": "MINIFIG", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] }, { "match_no": 0, "entries": [ { "item": { "no": "40453-1", "name": "Batman vs. The Penguin & Harley Quinn blister pack", "type": "INSTRUCTION", "category_id": 768 }, "color_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "extra_quantity": 0, "is_alternate": false, "is_counterpart": false } ] } ] }'));
      return users;
    }
  }
}

class _JsonParseDemoState extends State<JsonParseDemo> {
  Bricklink? _bricklink;
  var _loading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;
    Services.getUsers().then((bricklink) {
      setState(() {
        _bricklink = bricklink;
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_loading ? 'Loading...' : 'BrickLink'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: null == _bricklink ? 0 : _bricklink!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Bricklink bricklink = _bricklink!;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(bricklink.data[index].entries[0].item.no),
              subtitle: Text(bricklink.data[index].entries[0].item.name),
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                  child:
                      Text(bricklink.data[index].entries[0].quantity.toString())),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class JsonParseDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  //
  JsonParseDemo() : super();

  @override
  _JsonParseDemoState createState() => _JsonParseDemoState();
}
```

Comment: if it helpful please upvote the answer